# IOS swift TableView is there a way I can reuse them

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am new to IOS development and am using swift 3.0 . I have 2 custom TableViews that have identical layout. The only difference is the data coming back via Json URL . One TableView is called **HomePageC** and the other **UserProfileC** . How can I use what I have in Prototype HomePageC and reuse it in UserProfileC ? It is like having a homepage of data then seeing individual users data hence userProfile but same layout because I think it's redundant doing 2 TableViews that are identical .

This is the **HomePageC** code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomePageTVC


   cell.post.text = Posts[indexPath.row]
   cell.fullname.setTitle(FullName[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
   cell.fullname.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.fullname.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomePageC.Fullname_Click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   cell.comments.setTitle(Comments[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
   cell.comments.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.votes.setTitle(Votes[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
   cell.votes.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.time.text = Times[indexPath.row]
  cell.shares.setTitle(Shares[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
   cell.shares.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.location.text = Locations[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }
```

**UserProfileC** code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserProfileTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomePageTVC


        cell.post.text = Posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.fullname.setTitle(FullName[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.fullname.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.fullname.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomePageC.Fullname_Click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.comments.setTitle(Comments[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.comments.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.votes.setTitle(Votes[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.votes.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.time.text = Times[indexPath.row]
        cell.shares.setTitle(Shares[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.shares.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.location.text = Locations[indexPath.row]
        cell.vote_status.text = Votes[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }
```

I tried to cast it to HomePage but it gives an error any help would be great as i'm quite lost .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to have reusable table is to create a single separated `UITableViewController` in Storyboard and design your prototype cell there. Instead of having two different reuse identifiers — "HomePageTVC" and "UserProfileTVC" — you can now have a single one (just leave "UserProfileTVC"). Don't forget to set `dataSource` and `delegate` of the table view controller to itself.

Next step: add a **container view** to any view controller you want to reuse this table in (both HomePageC and UserProfileC controllers in your case).

[image: Container view]

Now just *Control+Drag* cursor from the created container views to your reusable table view controller in Storyboard to establish a **container** relationship.

Now you have a single `UITableViewController` class to put all cells management logic to, and you can easily load different data based on current `parentViewController` property — just check what type of controller your table is currently embedded in:

```
if parentViewController is HomePageC {
    // Load user data for Home page controller
} else if parentViewController is UserProfileC {
    // Load user data for user profile controller
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that sounds perfects